# RecyclerView inside HorizontalScrollView not showing all items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `HorizontalScrollView`. I don't see inside `RecyclerView` all the items. I have looked and even if the list in the adapter has 7 items, `onBindViewHolder` is called only 4 times! If I take out the `HorizontalScrollView`, it works ok.

I use the `HorizontalScrollView` because I need to scroll the list with the background of the recycle, not inside recycle, how it usually works.

[image]

So, I need a solution to scroll a list with the background of the list, or to show all the items using `HorizontalScrollView`

UPDATE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/label">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlWrapper"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/paddingStartView"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_round_corner">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/optionsRv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/paddingStartView"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/paddingEndView"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/rlWrapper" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        style="@style/FontLocalizedMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#979797"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Tempareature" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I dont understand what you want, ....."I need to scroll the list with the background from recycle, not inside recycle"

Comment: @ghita did you find any solution? I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: yes, i will edit question wih response

Comment: Thanks! I changed the child of HorizontalScrollView to RelativeLayout and it worked perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Make the child of the `HorizontalScrollView` to be `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`

Comment: right now, the child is a `recycleView`. you suggest to have the recycle wrap onto a RelativeLayout?

Comment: Great, it's working like charm. +100 likes

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into this too, and the accepted answer helped.  I had:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/dates_recycler"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and it didn't show all the items in the horizontally-oriented recycler view.  It only showed enough items that would fit in the width of the device view, call `onBindViewHolder` that many times, etc.  Adding a `RelativeLayout` in between the `HorizontalScrollView` and the `RecyclerView` fixed it, so that it showed all the items whether they fit all in the width of the device, or not, and you could scroll to reach them.

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/dates_recycler"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I *think* also setting the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to the `RelativeLayout` is key.

Comment: I think the only solution available in the market now..works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

`onBindViewHolder` is only called for the "visible on screen" items. If total item is 7 and the screen can only show 4, then everything is ok.

Hence the name "RecycleView", it recycles visible views, there are onle 4 views in total in your `RecycleView`

This I dont understand what you mean!?

> I use the HorizontalScrollView because I need to scroll the list with
>   the background from recycle, not inside recycle, how it usually works.
>
> So, I need a solution to scroll a list with the background of the
>   list, or to show all the items using HorizontalScrollView